# Is there a way to undo voting to close a question?

Tags: support, closing-questions

If I've voted to close a question, and realise that I was mistaken, is there a way to undo this?  (Assume that the question is not closed yet).  Clicking on close again just tells me that I've already done it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but your vote will expire harmlessly after a few days if 4 other people don't vote to close.

For reference, [a request to allow close vote undoing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) was declined on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I agree with the commenters there, unfortunately - it's crazy that you can't undo this mistake.