# What's with all the closure tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

<sup>Let's raise the tagging topic to a new level of meta-ness by talking about tags on **meta**!</sup>

We have four different tags on meta.SFF which are about question closure:

- [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) (81 questions): "*For questions about closing questions, or about a specific closed question.*"
- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) (58 questions): "*For use when discussing the principles and reasoning behind closing questions.*"
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) (31 questions): *no tag wiki*
- [closing](/questions/tagged/closing) (7 questions): *no tag wiki*

What's the difference in meaning and usage, if any, between these four tags? Should they be synonymised or merged together?

Comment: I can think of meaningfully specific and distinct definitions for these tags which arguably fit some of their existing uses, but imo the fact that you have to ask this and I have to *think* to come up with an answer means they're already failing as tags. If it's not immediately obvious whether a question does or does not fit under a certain tag, then askers are going to misuse it (or not use it at all), and then it serves no purpose. So I'd be happy to merge some of these.

Comment: Keep [tag:closed-questions] and make other 3, it's synonym

Comment: Does a few upvotes on your question and no votes on the answers mean that you can merge whatever you want, or that you shouldn’t do anything?

Comment: There’s a [meta-tag:delete] tag. Looks like 3 of those questions should be [meta-tag:deleted-questions], two should be [meta-tag:deleted-answers], and one should be something else, possibly [meta-tag:user-accounts].

Comment: @anaranjada Thanks! If you edit [these](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/how-can-i-get-an-answer-undeleted-once-ive-edited-it-to-conform-to-the-guidelin) two [questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/can-i-delete-an-answer-i-posted) to [deleted-answers] rather than [delete], then I can merge [delete] into [deleted-questions] and everything will be tagged correctly with the minimum amount of disturbance.

Comment: Done. I somehow figured out how to use the app... I think.

Comment: @anaranjada Thanks. I've now spent the last hour pondering whether to create a [tag:deleting-questions] tag analogous to [tag:closing-questions]. Eventually I decided not to, because: a) closing questions is a much more varied art, with different close reasons etc.; b) nearly all questions about deletion are of the form "why was X deleted?" rather than e.g. "should X be deleted?"; c) by analogy with [tag:deleted-answers] and [tag:deleted-comments]. So the deletion tag will be [tag:deleted-questions], even though [tag:closed-questions] won't be the only closure tag..

Answer (score 2):

Every time I went back to this issue and started to consider merging some of these tags, I stopped short of taking any action even on the least-used tag, [closing](/questions/tagged/closing) with 7 questions. Eventually, I realised what was nagging at me: **[closing](/questions/tagged/closing) is actually the best tag name of the four**, which is why I could never quite bring myself to merge it into any of the others.

### **What are these questions about? They're about [closing-questions](/questions/tagged/closing-questions).**

[close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) doesn't work as a tag for all of them, because not all questions about closure relate to the *reasons* for closure: e.g. [Are too many questions being closed by a moderator alone rather than the community?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/are-too-many-questions-being-closed-by-a-moderator-alone-rather-than-the-communi) or [Is there a way to undo voting to close a question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243/is-there-a-way-to-undo-voting-to-close-a-question)

[vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) *could* work as a tag for all these questions (barring the pedantic nitpick that moderators can't vote to close a question, only close it outright), since they're all about when, whether, or why users should vote to close questions. But this is a strange name for a tag anyway, and what really matters is whether a question actually gets closed, not whether it gets one or two votes to close.

Both the answers here propose merging [closing](/questions/tagged/closing) and [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) into [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons), since all three are used for questions "**about closing questions**". I agree that these three tags should be merged together, but if they're about closing questions, then let's call the master tag [closing-questions](/questions/tagged/closing-questions)!

---

I've now merged [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons), [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close), and [closing](/questions/tagged/closing) into a new tag called [closing-questions](/questions/tagged/closing-questions). I'll leave [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) for a bit, since nobody seems to have worked out yet whether its usage differs significantly from the other three, but I may end up merging that one into [closing-questions](/questions/tagged/closing-questions) too. Comments on this will be appreciated, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd pair serve no purpose. I can think of ways to use them as separate terms, but they're only being used the way the first two are.

The first two make sense, per their tag wikis.

[close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) should be what types of policies we have about closing questions, or which option to select when we vote to close when a question needs closing. Generally forward-thinking, even if inspired by a specific question.

[closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) should be about questions that are or were closed. Why specifically were they closed, if closing them was correct, if the close reason was correct, if they should be reopened, whatever.

By the looks of it, this *seems* like it's how the two tags are generally used, anyway. But there's the usual double-tagging and mix ups we get with related tags.

However, we already have [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), so I think it'd work just fine to make them all synonyms, and when it's about a question that's already closed or maybe should be, then use the additional tag.